# XMLWorkerHelper use new font while converting HTML text to iText ElementList

Tags: itext

I want to convert my HTML text to iText's [`ElementList`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.12/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/ElementList.html) with some new fonts.
I don't want to use `parseXHtml` function as I need the PDF text separately for each cell of my table.
Is there any way I can use my TTF font file while converting from HTML to `ElementList`.

I'm using:

```
ElementList el1 = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(chunk1Text, CSS);
```

to convert my HTML text to `ElementList` but if I specify a font like
"Courier New" in my HTML it doesn't render that font but defaults to "Times New Roman". How can I use that font?
As I mentioned earlier I want `ElementList` only from the HTML text not the converted PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712551/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-itextxmlworker-from-servlet-using-custom-font) regarding specific font handling.

Considering the PDF file generation itself, I'm used to build my own PDF table and fill its cells with something like below, the `htmlContext` and the `cssResolver` being defined as reusable class attributes:

```
private ElementList getElementsFromHtml(final String html) throws IOException {
    //...

    // Pipelines
    final ElementList elements = new ElementList();

    final ElementHandlerPipeline end = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
    final HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, end);
    final CssResolverPipeline cssPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

    // XML Worker
    final XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(cssPipeline, true);
    final XMLParser p = new XMLParser(true, worker, htmlContext.charSet());

    final String resolvedHtml = "<body>" + html + "</body>";
    p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(resolvedHtml.getBytes(htmlContext.charSet())), htmlContext.charSet());

    return elements;
}

public void addHtml(final PdfPCell cell, final String html) throws IOException {
    for (final Element e : getElementsFromHtml(html)) {
        if (ColumnText.isAllowedElement(e)) {
            cell.addElement(e);
        } else {
            LOG.error(String.format("### Element not allowed! ###\nElement (type: %d): %s\nContext: %s", e.type(), e.toString(), html));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868